# Estimate price azure when using Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I want to copy CSV file in Blob to another Blob by Data Factory. I want to estimate the cost I have to pay. So, What will affect the amount I have to check.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Factory pricing has several factors. You can find the current pricing [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/)
This is what it looks like today. 
[image: Data Factory Pricing]
[image: ADF Pricing 2]
If you are copying files from one blob to another, you can use the Azure integration runtime. The act of copying the file is considered an activity. DIUs are the compute resources that do the work. When the copy activity runs on an Azure integration runtime, the minimal allowed Data Integration Units (formerly known as Data Movement Units) is [two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance).

You didn't specify how often you want to copy the files from one blob to another, but that factors into how many DIU-hours you will use.

So if I assume the following:

- 1000 activity runs
- 30 DIU-hours
- No self-hosted IR, no data flows
- 1 entity unit of read/write operations
- 1 entity unit of monitoring operations

The [Azure Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?&OCID=AID2000128_SEM_brphHbCy&MarinID=brphHbCy_221166233986_azure%20pricing%20calculator_e_c_2AiPkuTD_44568975337_kwd-310354828215&lnkd=Google_Azure_Brand&gclid=CjwKCAjwpuXpBRAAEiwAyRRPgbnWtGFFvkoSKAAk1rLeW5mIxp6Qh_QXyCBfOb1kSZMIyj44KdtBrhoC8m8QAvD_BwE) gives me about $9 per month. You may come up with a different number if you adjust the activity runs and DIU-hours. If it is a single small file you are copying daily, you probably wouldn't use 30 DIU-hours. If it is actually 5 of the world's largest CSVs, and you copy them hourly, you might. The only real way to know the DIU hours is to build a pipeline and execute it once.

Answer (score -1):

The estimated amount you will pay is measured by AU hours. So you can run a job and see how much it will cost and then just do the mat.

For example. This job run 5 AU's for 33 seconds and it cost 0.07 EUR.

[image: test job]

You can see in the AU analysis if you switch the n# of AU's to use the cost and if its more efective use more AU's to lower the cost or if less AU's can do the same job for less money.

[image: AU analysis]

You can also try calculate the cost of any Azure services in the link provided by Azure:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/

Comment: I believe AU hours is related to Data Lake Analytics. Data Factory has a different pricing structure that does not have AU hours.